# Upgrading 4GB onboard SSD in my EEEPC4G

Tags: ssd, upgrade, eee-pc

I own an Asus EEEPC 4G and have installed Windows XP on it. The 4GB internal SSD is almost full and it keeps giving me regular warning of disk full. I have tried everything under the sun to create some space but it is not possible to go on.

I am now looking at upgrading the SSD card. I want to replace 4GB card with 32 or 64GB card and reinstall Windows.

Can you let me know if it is possible to remove and reinstall a new SSD card?
If so how?

Comment: Could you tell us the precise model of EEEPC you have?

Answer (score 2):

Before I say anything else: Whoa, that's an interesting computer. Pretty cool.

Anyway... about the mods. *(I'm just searching around on the internet, if it wasn't already obvious; I have no experience with Eee hardware.)*

- [This link](http://beta.ivc.no/wiki/index.php/Eee_PC_Internal_Upgrades) is a wiki of Eee PC upgrades, such as hacking a USB flash drive in as storage, but that takes serious hardware modding skills
- [this blog article](http://eeepc-albkwan.blogspot.com/2009/10/install-2nd-ssd-to-my-eeepc-4g.html) says it's sometimes possible to replace the wireless card with an ssd (I think?)
- [This **EeeUser Forums thread**](http://forum.eeeuser.com/index.php?/topic/55840-eee-pc-701-4g-ssdupgrades/) is the best info I've found so far; it looks like **the 4Gb SSD is soldered on to the motherboard** (and therefore not upgradeable), however some(?) of the shipped models have a mini-PCI slot that can support an SSD with hacking, and more importantly it's **relatively easy to put an sd card in and boot from it**.

Since there's such a large group of Eee PC enthusiasts (apparently), I think your best bet is to join a forum where people have hardware expertise with your system, and ask them for advice.